# Count of vegetation pixels of an image in R

Tags: r, count, pixel

I have 62 boolean png satellite images (3342 X 2213) where all vegetation pixels have floating vegetation masks. See the image:

[image: Floating vegetation masks]

1 values and non-vegetation have 0 values. How do I compute the number of vegetation pixels (1 values) for each image in R?

Comment: Have you tried `table()` ?

Comment: Trying anything and posting it here would be a help. If you have errors, posting them and what line causes it would also be helpful.

Comment: thanks Ravi. the table() seem to have worked. nc<-nc_open(filein,write=TRUE)
  x<-ncvar_get(nc,"floatvegmask")
  y<-table(x,exclude = 0)
  print(y)